# PHP image upload problems

Tags: php, html, image-uploading

I'm trying to create a website were pictures can be uploaded and saved into a folder in the server. However, the code does not go past the second if. Is there something I'm missing? Thanks in advance.

The PHP:

```
if (isset($_FILES["file"]["name"])){
        if($_FILES['image']['error']==0){
            $file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
            $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
            $image_name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);

            $newname = $erabiltzaile.".png"; 

            $target = 'irudiak/profile/users/'.$newname;
            move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['image']['name'], $target);

        }
    }else{
        $image=null;
        $image_name="";

    }
```

The HTML:

```
<div id='igoera'>
<input name='image' id ='image' type='file' accept='image/png' onchange='loadFile(event)' /><br /><br />
<img width='300' id='preview'/><br>
</div>
```

Comment: What happens if you echo `$_FILES['image']['error']`?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've missed `input file name` in your condition:

```
if (isset($_FILES["image"]["name"])){
```

Comment: Oh, yeah - I missed that one. It's always going to return false as it currently stands.

Comment: Hmm... Thanks a lot, but it doesn't work. I have more details in case that may help. I can't get the code past the very first line, it seems that it always returns false. I have tried with both `if (isset($_FILES["image"]["name"])){` and `if (isset($_FILES["file"]["name"])){` with no success.

Comment: what does `var_dump($_FILES["image"])` return at the moment?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It gives me an error (Undefined index: image) and returns NULL. I guess the image is not found correctly :(

Comment: check your `loadFile` function for errrors

Comment: loadFile works fine - it's just a function to preview the image before submitting the form.

Answer (score 0):

In the manual there's a section on file uploads http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php which shows the values for the error variable in the `$_FILES` array.

A successful upload should result in the error value being `UPLOAD_ERR_OK`.

So change the second `if` condition to:

```
if($_FILES['image']['error']=='UPLOAD_ERR_OK'){
```