# Can't upload image to website with PHP

Tags: php, html, ajax, image-uploading, image-upload

I asked a similar question about a week ago, but since I got no answer and the status of the code has changed quite a lot, I've decided to open a new thread. Hope there is no problem ;)

I'm creating a website where people can write comments. When doing so, a name and an image are asked for, and then displayed on the site. However, I can't get the images properly uploaded to my folder. Here's the form in HTML (which is displayed using AJAX):

```
<input name='image' id ='image' type='file' accept='image/jpg' />
```

Here the PHP that I use to upload the image (with no success...):

```
if($_FILES['image']['name']) {
        echo 'File has been uploaded by user';
        if(!$_FILES['image']['error']){
            echo 'No errors';
            $target = 'images/profile/users/'.$username.'.jpg';
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target);
            echo 'Should be uploaded';
        }
        else{
            echo 'Error:  '.$_FILES['image']['error'];
        }
    }
```

Whenever I try to upload a file, the first echo is not displayed (no 'File has been uploaded by user' is written on the screen). No other messages displayed, either... Any ideas?

Thanks a lot

Xabi

EDIT: someone has asked me how the form tag was written. Just in case that can help, here's that code:

```
<form id='writeComment' name='writeComment' method='POST' action='writeComment.php'>
```

Comment: Do you have `enctype` attribute within a `form` tag?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and you'll get plenty of undefined notices.

Comment: and you state Ajax but no code to support the question. Not enough code here including the form tags etc. If you're going to have everyone guessing, post your full code or fix it yourself. Sorry, that's called *tough love*.

Comment: Hi, sorry if the information was not enough, I thought it would be. The form tag doesn't have the `enctype` attribute, it just this: `<form id='writeComment' name='writeComment' method='POST' action='writeComment.php'>`.

Answer (score 0):

You should change this line

> $target = 'images/profile/users/'.$username.'.jpg';

To this:

$target = 'images/profile/users/'.$_FILES['image']['name'];

Comment: Why? This is the target filename.

Comment: Because the filename have .jpg or different types inside it.

So he is making this for example:

> images/profile/users/Example.jpg.jpg

Comment: You have ventured yourself into a possible very deep rabbit hole. The OP asked a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/q/34590212/ and failed to show us their full code. Good luck with this.

Comment: @fernando-sanchiz No he's making `username.jpg` whatever's in `$username` it probably doesn't have a file extension.

Comment: Hi! I wanted to save the image with the username as its name, so my image would be "trikuxabi.jpg". I only accept .jpg files in the form so that shouldn't be a problem. Thanks for your help :)